# Cuda register compiler optimization

Tags: c++, cuda, compiler-optimization

My question is rather simple I'm writing a CUDA application, but because my main computer is a Windows PC (Visual Studio 2013) I have developed my application there. But the end application is going to be deployed in a *nix server.

My question is:

On **Visual Studio 2013** optimziation flag **/Ox** (full optimization) with **/Oi** (enable intrinsics) manages to squeeze my register usage to just 32regs thus getting a full occupancy.

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0 --ptxas-options=-v --machine 64 --compile -cudart static     -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Ox /Zi  /MD " -o Simulation.cu.obj "Simulation.cu"
```

On **Ubuntu** using **gcc 4.9.4** and **cuda-8** compiled with **cmake** and **O3** optimization level, the register count is around 49 (>32).

```
nvcc Simulation.cu -dc -o Simulation.cu.o -ccbin cc -m64 -DNDEBUG -Xcompiler ,\"-std=c++1y\",\"-w\",\"-O3\",\"-g\" -arch=sm_35 -std=c++11 -rdc=true -O3 --ptxas-options=-v -DNVCC
```

Am I missing any flag ? And I don't want to spill any registers to local memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different versions of the toolkit (or even the driver, if you compile to PTX) may use different numbers of registers for the same code.

Use [launch bounds](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds) to inform the compiler of your intended launch configuration and occupancy goal for the specific kernel. If necessary, it will then try hard to bring down register use.
Whether that requires spilling registers to local memory is outside your control, but the compiler will generally behave very reasonable.

Comment: Since I want 100% occupancy why wouldn't I use -maxrregcount and rely on launch bounds, although thanks for the link, I didn't know their existence.
I'm baffled because ptx compilation shouldn't be platform specific and I would expect the same results in both platforms

Comment: -maxrregcount works equally well if you have a single kernel per compilation unit (.cu file). Per-kernel launch bound annotations were later added so each kernel can use it's optimal configuration.

Comment: PTX compilation isn't necessarily platform specific, but you are using different versions of the toolkit. New compiler versions very likely include additional optimizations and adjusted heuristics that would lead to different register use.

Comment: it turns out that the nix version doesn't perform any register allocation unless told to do so unless maxrregcount or launch bounds are specified.

In my case both maxrregcount and launch bounds didn't spill anything to local memory. I was mislead from the nvprof --metrics because sometimes the kernel's blocks are few and do not saturate the card.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: "the nix version doesn't perform any register allocation unless..." - not sure what that is supposed to tell me since register allocation is an essential step in compiling any code. But I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Not exactly, register allocation is not essential and shouldn't be done in -O0 optimization (spill everything). As far as cuda is concerned -O0 yielded 45 registers and -O3 yielded 45 registers, which would be a 1-1 var to register alloc and I wouldn't say it optimized anything.